# Processing large files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unix

What is the best way of processing very large files in php.
This is my current the scenario:

1. I extract a raw file from a Network Mgmt System (NMS) about all parameters of all network elements (NMS is running in a UNIX box).
2. I FTP the raw file in my PC box using PHP.
3. I process the raw file line by line using the PHP's fget() function.
4. Every line i use string matching and regexp matching to extract necessary data until i am able to compose 1 line of necessary data separated by commas (",").
5. I repeat step 4 until EOF and have the full CSV file.
6. I then throw this data to my database using sql's "LOAD DATA INFILE"

My problem now is, I have 1 raw file that reaches more/less 200MB, and has more/less 180 columns of data and because of these my php script cannot finish proccessing the whole file because upon processing it is exhausting all the 1024MB memory I allocate on my php.ini file.

Hoping to have recomendations on the best workaround of this problem. Thanks!

code of the processing part below:

```
while( !feof($fh) ){
set_time_limit(0);
$l_buffer = fgets( $fh, $fsize );
$l_LineStream = explode( ' ', trim( $l_buffer ) );
$l_FilteredLineStream = array_filter( $l_LineStream, array( $this, 'RemoveEmptyElement' ) );
$l_GrepMatchArray = preg_grep( '/^BSC.*_.*$/', $l_FilteredLineStream );
if( count( $l_GrepMatchArray ) > 0 ){
    foreach( $l_GrepMatchArray as $l_BSCFound ){
        $l_BSCFound = explode( '_', $l_BSCFound );
        $l_BSCHoming = $l_BSCFound[1];
    }
}
$l_GrepMatchArray = preg_grep( '/^BTS-[0-9]*$/', $l_FilteredLineStream );
if( count( $l_GrepMatchArray ) > 0 ){
    foreach( $l_GrepMatchArray as $l_BTSFound ){
        $l_CurrBTS = $l_BTSFound;
    }
}
/**/
if( $l_PrevBTS != $l_CurrBTS && isset( $l_BTSArray ) && count( $l_BTSArray ) > 0 ){
    #$this->BTS_Array[] = $l_BTSArray;
    if( $l_FirstLoop == true ){
        $this->WriteDataToCSVFile( $l_BTSArray, $l_FilePath, true );
        $l_FirstLoop = false;
    }else{
        $this->WriteDataToCSVFile( $l_BTSArray, $l_FilePath );
    }
}
/**/
if( count( $l_GrepMatchArray ) > 0 ){
    #var_dump( $l_FilteredLineStream );
    $l_BTSArray = $this->InstantiateEmptyBTSArray();
    #$l_BTSArray['CI'] = '';
    $l_BTSArray['BSC'] = $l_BSCHoming;
    $l_BTSArray['BCF'] = $l_FilteredLineStream[0];
    $l_BTSArray['BTS'] = $l_FilteredLineStream[3];
    $l_BTSArray['CELL NAME'] = $l_FilteredLineStream[6];
}
if( $l_GetPLMNNextLineData == true && isset( $l_BTSArray['PLMN'] ) ){
    $l_BTSArray['PLMN'] .= trim( $l_buffer );
    $l_GetPLMNNextLineData = false;
}
$l_GrepMatchArray = preg_match( '/\.\(.*$/', $l_buffer, $reg_match );

if( count( $reg_match ) > 0 ){
    $l_KeyName = substr( $reg_match[0], 2, strpos( $reg_match[0], ')' ) - 2 );
    preg_match( '/[[:space:]].*|[-].*/', $reg_match[0], $param_value );
    $l_BTSArray[$l_KeyName] = trim( $param_value[0] );
    if( $l_KeyName == 'PLMN' ){
        $l_GetPLMNNextLineData = true;
    }
}
$l_PrevBTS = $l_CurrBTS;
}
```

Comment: How do i do that? Im sorry if it sound so dumb, but im not very much familiar with how do things work around here.. Thanks for ur consideration.

Comment: you choose an answer when you get a good one...

Comment: See FAQ or : http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: Without code there's no way to answer this question.  My crystal ball is only getting the shopping channel at the moment.

Comment: @GordonM: I don't think a relative broad question about a workflow / best practice needs code... although some details here hint at a problem at code level (as already mentioned by others) Jayzee: sounds like a good excuse to learn awk or perl and process the file on the unix box ;)

Comment: I cannot do string processing inside the NMS server because it would eat to much resources in the server. The server is live and catering remote monitoring of all live cell sites. I FTP it to another pc so that the resources needed will be provided by this local PC.

Comment: What does '4096' mean which i usually i see in fgets( file, '4096' ). On my fget function i put the filesize of the file in the '4096' param of the fxn.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your script is really processing the big file line by line (one line at a time).

- do you keep a read line in an array?
- do you write the CSV line instantly in your file, or do you keep all the generated lines in an array?
- etc.

If you process the file line by line, it should not use 1GB+ memory.

Comment: Its processing the big file, I actually see the output but not complete since the the script already exhuasted the memory i allocate.I write it instantly on the file and after writing, I overwrite the varuables i used for every 1 complete line (data separated by ",")

Answer (score 0):

Why do you save to MySQL only in the end of process?
When you parsed a line flush that to the database, so you will just use few MB for each rows.

### To address the comment:

You can use `INSERT DELAYED` to let database manage the load, and to don't stress it too much

Comment: If I do that, I will cause to much traffic over the network and may cause the MySQL server to response to other request very slowly or worst wont be able to respond to other requests.

Comment: @Jayzee: i have edidted my answer to address your problem easly

Answer (score 0):

If you are running out of 1024MB of memory processing a 200MB file then I would suggest you have a memory issue somewhere. I would suggest you check your code for areas that could be holding on to resources that are no longer required.

Comment: OK, I'll try to rigorously examine my script once more.